# Looking for a scalable "at" implementation

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, high-availability, scheduled-tasks

I'm looking for a scalable "at" replacement, with high availability. It must support adding and removing jobs at runtime.

Some background:
I have an application where I trigger millions of events, each event occurs just once. I don't need cron like mechanisms (first Sunday of the month, etc), simply date, time and context.

Currently I'm using the [Quartz scheduler](http://quartz-scheduler.org/), and while it is a very good project, it has difficulties to handle the amount of events we throw at it, even after a lot of tweaking (sharding, increasing polling interval, etc.) due to the basic locking it performs on the underline database. Also, it is a bit overkill for us, as basically we have millions of one time triggers, and relatively small number of jobs.

I'd appreciate any suggestion

Comment: What are your requirements around failure? For example, if a machine goes down, would you want the "missed" events to fire when a replacement comes up?

Comment: Yes, similar to Quartz. Also, I run Quartz in a cluster, so there is always a warm machine waiting (in Quartz all nodes compete every time they need to poll the DB for jobs)

Comment: I was just wondering how simple we could make things *without* Quartz. If every job has to be acknowledged though, that makes it trickier. What's the penalty if a job runs twice? (For example, could you acknowledge all jobs executed in the last minute, once a minute?)

Comment: I can't run jobs twice, as some of them send messages to users. Job acknowledgement is just one issue, such as having the right data store for quick fetches and updates, having it done in a distributed manner and so on. This is why I'm looking for an off the shelf project rather than implementing one myself.

Comment: Have you had a look at [Akka](http://akka.io)? It has schedulers you can set up. I've dabbled with the schedulers a bit in a project using the Playframework, but nothing to that scale. Their website says it can handle a lot

Comment: If you decide to use Akka, it's worth to read about [its performance](http://letitcrash.com/post/20397701710/50-million-messages-per-second-on-a-single-machine).

Comment: Akka indeed look nice, my only concern with it is the durability of the messages

Comment: Presumably, your events will be triggered using messages. So, maybe [Durable Mailboxes](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/modules/durable-mailbox.html) in Akka would be a proper choice.

Comment: @nobeh this is definitively interesting, I will give it a look

Comment: I am afraid the scheduler in Akka is not persistent. While you can have durable mailboxes - this is not the same. Have you tried Quartz with Terracotta instead of JDBC for scaling?

Comment: @Tomasz Nurkiewicz Yes we have, unfortunately it didn't work as promised. The database implementation was better

Answer (score 1):

If I was facing the same scenario I would do the following...

Setup a JMS queue cluster (e.g RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ) using a queue replication setup over a few boxes.

Fire all the events at my nice highly-available JMS queue.

Then I would code an agent application that popped the events of the JMS queue as needed, I could run multiple agents on multiple boxes and have that combined with the correct JMS failover url etc.

You could also use the same sort of model if your jobs are firing the events...

Fyi, a nicer way of scheduling in core Java is as follows:

```
ScheduledExecutorService threadPool = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(sensibleThreadCount);
    threadPool.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
       //Pop events from event queue.
       //Do some stuff with them.
    }

    }, initialDelay, period, TimeUnit.X);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just use [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org) [shared tree](http://www.jgroups.org/javadoc-3.x/org/jgroups/blocks/ReplicatedTree.html) with tasks sorted by execution time. Nodes will will take first task and schedule timer, which will execute at given time. On task remove timer can be canceled.
So basically you can use just JGroups and simple java Timers/Executors.

I didn't read it whole, but here is some [proof of concept or maybe even solution](http://www.jgroups.org/taskdistribution/TaskDistribution.html)

Answer (score -1):

how about the java timer?

```
import java.util.*;

public class MyTask extends TimerTask{
   public void run(){
       System.out.println( "do it!" );
   }
}
```

and then

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

MyTask job1 = new MyTask();
// once after 2 seconds
timer.schedule( job1, 2000 );

job1.cancel();

MyTask job2 = new MyTask(); 
// nach each 5 seconds after 1 second
timer.schedule  ( job2, 1000, 5000 );
```

Comment: 1. It doesn't survive process restart; 2. How do you scale it to millions of jobs? This is what Quartz aims to solve

Comment: 1. You didn't mention persistence is a requirement; 2. You said there are relatively small number of jobs.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I did mention "High availability" and "Millions of events/Millions of one-time triggers"...